# Can Syntax Errors be handled?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Consider the following code:

```
try:
    if True a = 1  #It's missing a colon So it's a SyntaxError!!!!!!!
except SyntaxError:
    print 'hey'
```

You'd expect it to print `hey` However It raises a `SyntaxError`, The same error I'm trying to avoid. So Can all Exceptions be handled using a `try-except` block? Well If `SyntaxError`'s were an exception why is it included in the [built-in exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError)? and finally how can I fix the above piece of code so that it handles the exception properly?

*Note: I know what I'm trying to do Is utterly pointless and serves no real purpose*

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`SyntaxError` is a perfectly ordinary built-in exception. It is not special in any way. Only the circumstances of when it's (usually) thrown are a bit unusual.

A syntax error means that the code featuring said error **cannot be parsed**. It doesn't even begin to be a valid program, hence it cannot be executed. Therefore `SyntaxError` exceptions are raised *before* the program is run, and hence can't be caught from within the program.

More specifically, this exception is raised by the parser. Because the parser runs fully before the code is executed, rather then interleaved with it, a program can't catch its own syntax errors.

The parser itself is just another program though: Code invoking the parser can catch `SyntaxError`s like every other exception (because it *is* like every other exception). Examples of "invoking the parser" include:

- `compile`, `exec`, `eval`
- `import` statements
- Several functions in modules like `ast`, `tokenizer`, `parser`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Of course you need `SyntaxError` as a built-in exception - what else should be raised if the compiler/parser encounters a syntax error?

You're right that this error usually happens at compile time, which is before you're able to catch it (runtime). (And how would you recover from it?)

I can think of one exception, though:

```
>>> try:
...    eval("hello =")
... except SyntaxError:
...    print("Hey! Who's using eval() anyway??")
...
Hey! Who's using eval() anyway??
```

Comment: so some `SyntaxError`s can be handled but not all?

Comment: @MattDMo: Well, if the SyntaxError arises at runtime, then it can be caught. How would a program handle a compile-time syntax error in a meaningful way?

Comment: @TimPietzcker So can my snippet be fixed to handle the exception?

Comment: @KDawG: No, of course not. As you wrote yourself, this would be utterly pointless.

Comment: Well, I guess the OP could wrap the whole thing in `exec`, i.e. `exec """ code """`, inside the `try` block.  Pretty ugly, though.