# Exception before the program starts Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If in my code, I mistakenly put this in

```
print "Hello "=name
```

instead of

```
print "Hello "+name
```

there would be a box saying SyntaxError. Would it be possible to try except that error??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Syntax Errors be handled properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816332/can-syntax-errors-be-handled-properly)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I catch a SyntaxError raised by eval'd code, but not caused by the source code itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856408/why-can-i-catch-a-syntaxerror-raised-by-evald-code-but-not-caused-by-the-sourc)