# try except not catching the exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

I was taught that an empty `except` catches all kinds of exceptions, but when I try this block of code it doesn't catch the exception and raise a `SyntaxError`. What am I doing wrong?

```
try:
    print "Hello"
except:
    print("Caught!")  #output: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Hello")?
```

even when I specify the kind of exception as `SyntaxError`it still doesn't catch it.

```
try:
    print "Hello"
except SyntaxError:
    print("Caught!") #output: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Hello")?
```

Comment: Forget about trying to catch that exception and just use `from __future__ import print_function` instead. (See also [What is \_\_future\_\_ in Python used for and how/when to use it, and how it works](//stackoverflow.com/q/7075082))

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816332/can-syntax-errors-be-handled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. An empty except catches all types of *runtime* errors; a syntax error is not a runtime error by definition, because the code can't run at all.

Comment: You got to it first! @Ayxan The code is not able to compile.

Comment: –1  syntax errors can occur at runtime.  and they can be caught at runtime too.