# how do I prevent python exe from closing when an error occurs

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, exe

```
try:
    some code here
except Exception as e:
    print("error: ",e)
```

here if this python exe code produces an exception it immediately closes the exe terminal
how do I stop it from exiting the exe terminal so that I can understand what exception exactly occurred
also I cant run it in CMD I have to run the exe file only
also I cant use the press any key method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Syntax Errors be handled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816332/can-syntax-errors-be-handled)

Comment: hi thank you for responding but this is just an example however in my code syntax error will not be a problem

Comment: i thought of the same solution that i will write the errors into an excel sheet or csv file maybe just wanted to know if there is any other option by which the error will be displayed on the screen if there is any error during the execution in my absence as i am going to run this through-out the day

Answer (score 0):

The terminal closes when the program terminates. When you catch the exception, you print your error message, and then the program terminate, so you don't really gain much from catching the exception; in fact, you even get less (you don't print the stack trace).

To get the stacktrace, look into [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html):

```py
try:
    foo = 123 / 0
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exception(e)
```

Then you need to have the program wait a bit that you can actually see the stack trace and error you print. A simple way is to just wait for input:

```py
try:
    foo = 123 / 0
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exception(e)
    wait_for_it = input('Press enter to close the terminal window')
```

Or you could add a break point to have the [Python debugger pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) come up. (It does at least on Mac OS when I run this code in a terminal, no idea about Windows.) See the above link for help on it, or type `help` at its prompt.

```py
try:
    foo = 123 / 0
except Exception as e:
    breakpoint()
```

Speaking of terminal: if you just open a command prompt or bash terminal, you can just run your code with `python3 myprog.py` and that terminal does not automatically close, so that you can see the output without modifying the program. Depending on how you run your code and what module dependencies you have, this may need a bit more setup (like a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)) but is probably worth it in the long run.